# Putting timestamp onto x axis in Flotr2 line graph

Tags: php, javascript, flotr

I am fairly new to Flotr2 and I have just been building some simple line graphs. That is simple enough and very cool. However, I need to put a timestamp (month day year plus time of day) as my x axis. I am getting the time from my database so its in php code and I am just echoing out the data like so:

```
while($stmt11->fetch()){
                echo " [" . $date_of_completion . ", " . $score . "]";
                echo ",";
                $i++;
                $total_score += $score;
            }
            echo "];";
```

And I have made the mode of the xaxis be "time" and I've tried "date", and it just never works. It keeps putting everything between 2001-2002 which is completely wrong, so I assume it just doesn't know what to do with the data I've given it. Has anyone else encountered this problem? I've looked through the example they give on time, but it makes no sense to me.

Any help at all would be really appreciated. Thanks

EDIT
Ok here is some more code. This is exactly what I'm doing to get the data out of the php and convert it to the format that flotr2 wants.

```
if(!($stmt11 = $mysqliprivate->prepare("SELECT date_of_completion, score FROM ". $shs . " WHERE id = ? ORDER BY date_of_completion ASC"))){
            echo "Prepare Failed: (" . $mysqliprivate->errno . ") " . $mysqliprivate->error;
        }
        else{
            $total_score = 0;
            $stmt11->bind_param("s", $id);
            $stmt11->execute();
            $stmt11->bind_result($date_of_completion, $score);
            $time = time();

            echo "var dataset = [";
            $i = 0;
            while($stmt11->fetch()){
                $date = date("U", strtotime($date_of_completion));
                echo " [" . $date . ", " . $score . "]";
                echo ",";
                $i++;
            }
            echo "];";
            $stmt11->close();
        }
```

And here is the javascript that I am running:

```
graph = Flotr.draw(container, [ 
            { data : dataset, label : 'Historical Patient Scores', lines:{show:true}, points: {show:true}}
            ], {
            xaxis: {
                minorTickFreq: 4,
                title : 'Date of Completion',
                tickDecimals: 0,
                noTicks: 10,
                mode : 'time',
                timeformat : '%y/%m/%d'
            }, 
            yaxis : {
                max : 30,
                title : 'Score',
                tickDecimals:0,
                min: 0
            },
            grid: {
                minorVerticalLines: true

            },
            legend : {
                position : 'nw'
            },
            mouse: {
                track: true,
                relative:true,
                trackDecimals:0,
                sensibility: 5
            }
        });
    })(document.getElementById("editor-render-0"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after @Chase and I have been trying to get this to work for a while, I think I got it. 
I hacked together my own tickFormatter function. There really wasn't much documentation for it, but some simple javascript knowledge was enough for it. 
So to get the epoch time I just did this:

```
                    echo "var dataset = [";
            $i = 0;
            while($stmt11->fetch()){
                            $temp = strtotime($date_of_completion);
                            echo " [" . $temp . ", " . $score . "]";
                echo ",";
                     }
            echo "];";
            $stmt11->close();
```

Then to get the time to show up properly instead of it just being crazy numbers this is what I hacked together:

```
xaxis: {
                minorTickFreq: 4,
                title : 'Date of Completion',
                tickDecimals: 0,
                noTicks: 20,

                mode : 'time',
                labelsAngle : 45,
                tickFormatter: function(x){
                    var x = parseInt(x);
                    var myDate = new Date(x*1000);
                    var string = myDate.getFullYear();
                    string = string + "-" + myDate.getMonth() + "-" + myDate.getDate();
                    result = string;
                    return string;
                }


            },
```

and then if you want the mouse-over to produce the same results put this code inside the mouse thing:

```
mouse: {
                track: true,
                relative:true,
                trackDecimals:0,
                sensibility: 5,
                trackFormatter: function(o){
                    var t = parseInt(o.x);
                    var myDate = new Date(t*1000);
                    var string = myDate.getFullYear();
                    string = string + "-" + myDate.getMonth() + "-" + myDate.getDate();
                    return string + ", " + o.y;
                }
            }
```

All of the rest of the javascript and php remain the same as in my original question at the top.

Answer (score 3):

The `time` mode takes a time value, so convert your date to Epoch time in milliseconds. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for how to convert a date to Epoch time, and remember php uses seconds (not ms like JavaScript and Flotr2). You'll also need to set the `timeformat` on the x-axis to a given format, like: `%m/%d/%y`

**After passing in the epoch time:**

```
         xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%m/%d/%y"
        },
```

This will convert the time back to a date format label.

You can use the following:

```
  %h: hours
  %H: hours (left-padded with a zero)
  %M: minutes (left-padded with a zero)
  %S: seconds (left-padded with a zero)
  %d: day of month (1-31), use %0d for zero-padding
  %m: month (1-12), use %0m for zero-padding
  %y: year (four digits)
  %b: month name (customizable)
  %p: am/pm, additionally switches %h/%H to 12 hour instead of 24
  %P: AM/PM (uppercase version of %p)
```

Comment: Ok so i've converted my date into epoch time using time($date). Then I fed those numbers into the graph and set the mode to be "mode: '%m/%d/%y' " but it just displays the large numbers instead of converting. If I change it to be mode : 'time' then I get the x axis to be jan1-jan15 which doesn't correspond to my dates at all, so all my points are on one side of the graph.

Comment: Leave `mode` as `time`, `timeformat` is a separate parameter for the x-axis. Please see the updated answer above, I hope it helps.

Comment: I've tied exactly as you said, but for some reason it still isn't working. It doesn't seem to understand the time that I give it because it doesn't convert it properly to the right dates. It just keeps putting them onto the same x point. To get the epoch time its just $temp = time($date_of_completion) right?

Comment: I believe you should be using `date()`, like so: `date ('U', $date_of_completion)` ...also if you'd rather do it with javascript: `new Date("04/28/2012").getTime()`

Comment: hmm still not working for some reason. Don't worry about it, I'm sure its just a random mistake I have. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: If there's any way I can see more code then I'd be glad to help more, however without having a whole lot to go on I'm not sure what else to say. If you find the answer, please post it here so we can update the answer for others that may have the same issue in the future.

Comment: I added in the code that I am using basically verbatim. If you can see what I am doing wrong I would really appreciated the help. Thanks!

Comment: Try `timeFormat`, I apologize if the case is what caused part of the issue. If that doesn't help we could try to write our own `tickFormatter` function. I've done some research on this as well and haven't found a whole lot. I'll try to give a better response once I get home from work. The documentation is fairly basic on many of the charting APIs I've seen, but I'm positive we'll figure it out! =)

Comment: Ok I think I got it. I was working on hacking together my own tickFormatter right as you commented again haha. It all works for me now. Thanks a lot for all of your help!!!

Comment: I think your problem is that it's not the standard Epoch time.  It expects a value in milliseconds since the beginning of the epoch (Jan 1, 1970).  I'm pretty sure php uses seconds, but since we're dealing in JavaScript, we get to use milliseconds, just like the Date constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is very simple... in order to use the built in formatter, you have to pass in **Date objects** in Javascript. Like this...

```
var dataArray = [[new Date('08/16/2012 03:40:15.000'),21.8917228040536],
                 [new Date('08/16/2012 03:40:15.000'),21.8917228040536]]
```

Look at your final rendered Javascript for clues - the PHP code doesn't make this issue clear.